# Generate attribute name in a loop, nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I am using the following code to generate a set of fields in a rails(3.06) form:

```
<% (1..5).each do |index| %>  
  <%= f.text_field "s"+index.to_s + "_incidence", :placeholder => "incidence", :value => number_to_percentage("s"+index.to_s + "_incidence", :precision => 0  ) %>                                                       
<% end %>
```

The loop creates fields - s0_incidence, s1_incidence, s2_incidence, etc.  depending on the number of requests in the project. So instead of repeating each line 10 times, I use the loop to create the fields.

The form submits correctly, however for existing records, I would like to populate the :value using number_to_percentage formula.  number_to_percentage refuses to recognize attribute name, so the contents of the cell look like "s0_incidence" instead of ##%.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to convert *"s"+index.to_s + "_incidence"* to symbol to have it recognized as :s0_incidence?

Answer (score 2):

`number_to_percentage` wants a number. It knows nothing of your form or model so it can't take a parameter name.

If I'm understanding your requests model correctly I think you need to do

```
<% @project.requests.each_with_index do |request, index| %>
  <%= f.text_field "s#{index}_incidence", :placeholder => "incidence", :value => number_to_percentage(request.incidence, :precision => 0) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: aNoble, thanks for the quick response. I don't think I was clear, so I updated the previous question to make it better.

Comment: @Alex, aNoble told you, where is your problem. number_to_percentage function can't understand, what do you want passing to it some string. It needs an numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
<% (1..5).each do |index| %>  
  <%= f.text_field "s"+index.to_s + "_incidence", :value => number_to_percentage(f.object["s"+index.to_s + "_incidence"], :precision => 0), :placeholder => "incidence" %>                                                       
<% end %>
```